# "Remote" login on a 3rd party website

Tags: authentication, request

I'm having a rather general question, in the sense that I'm not even sure that it's possible.  I'm trying to gather some opinions about it, coming from more experienced people.

Imagine, that I'm a member of three (just to say a number) online book stores.  Over the years I have bought quite some books on all three accounts.  Now, let's say I want to create an application that can login to these three accounts and do server requests to sort all my books in a single list.  So that I can access my books from a single location, similar to what Pidgin or Trillian does with multiple instant messenger services.

Is that even a realistic option?  Of course I dont *know* which server requests I would have to do and/or in which data format the data will be sent back. Assuming that this doesn't infringe every EULA out there, how would you approach this?

It's all a bit vague, but that's all I have at the moment :)

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to talk to each server via its own API (assuming it has one). You can then get the relevant info from each server and process it in your app (e.g. get the common info, aggregate it in a single list, sort...).

This is more or less what pidgin/trillian do.

IMHO the more interesting problem occurs when you want to buy a new book via your app :)

Comment: I assume that I'd have to approach each website differently indeed.  I know about a website which supplies a (very basic) API.  But what about stores who don't supply such an API?  Are there tools available to learn about how a website communicates with the server (as in: which queries it performs to get the needed data) ?

Comment: If the side doesn't have an API, things are quite difficult imo. The thing is that even if you mange to create custom queries, you'll have to do some screen scraping to get the desired info.